# getting the state of navbar in bootstrap 4 using React js

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to toggle some styling depending on whether the navbar is opened or closed (in mobile and tablet views), I have seen solutions for jQuery but i want to do it in react js.

i have tried setting a state on the hamburger button and toggling it on user interaction but it's really not a good solution and it's flawed since sometimes the user can close the navbar without clicking the hamburger button, instead i want to get the actual state of the navbar

is this possible in react js? if so how?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: i would like to see a guide or a solution @keikai

Comment: I would like to see the code you've attempted so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean state variable and toggle it when the Hamburger is clicked...

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showNav: true };
    this.toggleNav = this.toggleNav.bind(this);
}

toggleNav() {
    this.setState({ 
        showNav: !this.state.showNav
    })
}
```

In the Navbar markup...

```
<nav>
   <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" onClick={this.toggleNav}>
       <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div className={(showNav ? 'show' : '') + ' collapse navbar-collapse'}>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/z0rSHluhPi

Comment: that is exactly what i have attempted so far, but i have been doing some stuff in the wrong way, yours is true, thanks

Comment: Great, make sure you post the code you tried in the question itself